# Java on screen notification for Win 8.1 PC

Tags: java, windows

[image]

Is there anyway to make a Windows notification like this with Java?

Comment: Not with pure java. You would likely need to make a windows dll, and use JNI to interop with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the `SystemTray` class to create a `TrayIcon` and use the method `displayMessage` to create a notification.